# Android RecyclerView only displays items after closing and restarting the app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a strange effect with my RecyclerView after I updated my App to API 28. I have a search button that triggers a search of Wifi devices in my area. The items are no longer displayed directly in the list. I have to close and reopen the app to get the correct display.

I have a toast that should be displayed when the button is pressed. The toast message is also only displayed after closing and opening the app.

**Activity.kt**

```
   private fun setFloatingSearchButton() {
        floating_button_discover_devices.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Search for new devices ...",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("Action", null).show()

            discoverDevices()

            registerReceiver(mWifiReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))

            mWifiManager!!.startScan()
        }
    }
```

**WifiAdapter.java**

```
public class WifiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WifiAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final int CONFIGURE_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE = 0x00000001;

    private static final String TAG = "WifiAdapter";

    private List<DeviceWifiTo> wifis;

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public WifiAdapter(List<DeviceWifiTo> wifis) {
        this.wifis = wifis;
    }

    @Override
    public WifiAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        activity = (Activity) context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View wifiView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_wifi, parent, false);

        return new WifiAdapter.ViewHolder(wifiView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WifiAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DeviceWifiTo wifi = wifis.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, wifi.getSsid());
        TextView wifiName = holder.wifiName;
        wifiName.setText(wifi.getSsid());

        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigureDeviceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ssid", wifi.getSsid());
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CONFIGURE_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wifis.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView wifiName;
        CardView cardView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            wifiName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_wifi_name);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_device);
        }
    }

}
```

**UcDiscoverDevicesImpl.java**

```
private void createRecyclerView(List<DeviceWifiTo> list) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_wifi);
    WifiAdapter adapter = new WifiAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity.getApplicationContext()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `layout manager` before set `adapter` to `recycler view`, Update like below

```
private void createRecyclerView(List<DeviceWifiTo> list) {
   RecyclerView recyclerView = activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_wifi);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity.getApplicationContext()));
   WifiAdapter adapter = new WifiAdapter(list);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to show your result in recyclerView. Do you have any callback methods for Your search?

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() in that callback method (set result then call notifyDataSetChanged() )

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up `layoutmanager` before setting the `adapter`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in kotlin just because of not adding the `notifyDataSetChanged()` where I am setting the data.